# Is there a hook I can use to alter the way comments are rendered?

Tags: comments

Is there a hook I can use to alter the way comments are rendered? Not for altering the comments form, but the listed comments themselves. Obviously, I can target with CSS, but I was wondering if I can hook into core and change the way they are displayed from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`hook_comment_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_view/7):

> The comment is being viewed. This hook can be used to add additional data to the comment before theming.

e.g.

```
function hook_comment_view($comment, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // how old is the comment
  $comment->time_ago = time() - $comment->changed;
}
```

Or use a standard theme preprocess hook

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  // Make changes to $vars that will be available in comment.tpl.php
}
```

You can also override the standard [comment.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.tpl.php/7) file in your theme to have full control over the markup.